# Two-head one way finite memory machine accepts non-regular languages

Tags: automata, computation-models

I'm having trouble proving, or understanding why a two-head one-way finite memory machine could accept a non-regular language– for instance, $(w \mid w \in (a,b)^{*}, w= a^i b^i, i\geq 0)$.

For clarity, a two-head one-way finite memory machine works as follows –    it has  a   finite  control and a read-only input tape. The input tape  contains a  string, with a  special blank symbol at the right end. The  machine starts in the start state with both heads on the first symbol of    the input string. In one step the machine reads the current symbols under the two read heads, moves one or both of the heads one position to    the right, and  changes state. Each step of the machine is uniquely determined  by  its current state and the symbols read by the two heads. (That is, the machine  is deterministic.)  The machine accepts the input string    if  it  reaches an  accepting   state.

Comment: Suppose I gave you a string of text and asked you to determine if it was a palindrome. Think about how you, as a human being, might do that by pointing at characters with your index fingers. Then implement that algorithm as a machine.

Comment: That wouldn't satisfy the one-way restriction, though.

Answer (score 7):

Just a "visual" Hint :-D

```
H1: v
    A A A B B B $
H2: ^

H1:   v
    A A A B B B $
H2: ^

H1:     v
    A A A B B B $
H2: ^

H1:       v        // found "B" ... let's
    A A A B B B $  // count both sides
H2: ^

H1:         v
    A A A B B B $  // ... go on ...
H2:   ^

H1:           v
    A A A B B B $  // ... go on ...
H2:     ^

H1:             v
    A A A B B B $  // H1 is on $, H2 on (the first) B ...
H2:       ^
```